# Create tables based on the rows value in a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

My requirement is some thing like this

I have a table tblDetails which contains all the details about the table

```
TblCol TblName ColNo ColName Type Length Sacle KeyType description
```

Now based on values in tblDetails  I want to create the tables.

Comment: Go ahead, what's stopping you?

Comment: need help how to write the query which will automatically create the table

Comment: You need concatenate the dynamic sql to create the table based on the configuration.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly i want.

Comment: actually tblDetails store the table name and column all these details and i want to select the tbldetails table and create the table.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (very) basic example of how to approach this sort of dynamic SQL.  This example does not add indexes, keys, or anything fancy - just some tables and columns with datatypes, but it should get you started in the right direction:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tblName nvarchar(255)

DECLARE tbl_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT tblName 
    FROM tblDetails
    ORDER BY tblName

OPEN tbl_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @tblName

--OUTER LOOP THROUGH TABLES:
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tblName + '( ';

    DECLARE @colName nvarchar(255),
            @type nvarchar(50),
            @length nvarchar(50),
            @ctr int = 0;

    DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT [colName], [Type], [Length]
        FROM tblDetails
        WHERE tblName = @tblName
        ORDER BY ColNo
    OPEN col_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @colName, @type, @length
    --INNER LOOP THROUGH COLUMNS   
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
    BEGIN
        IF @ctr != 0 --if this is not the first column, prefix w/ comma
            SET @sql += ', ';

        SET @sql += '[' + @colName + '] ' + @type;

        IF @type IN ('CHAR','VARCHAR','NCHAR','NVARCHAR','BINARY','VARBINARY') --add size if appropriate
            SET @sql += '(' + @length + ')'

        SET @ctr += 1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @colName, @type, @length
    END --inner loop

    CLOSE col_cursor

    SET @sql += ')';
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM tbl_cursor INTO @tblName   
END --outer loop   

CLOSE tbl_cursor
```